# Why the difference between the RSSI and Rx Level measurements is so big?

Tags: rf, telecommunications, power-measurement

I'm new in Telecom. Today, I downloaded the Android APK called "Network Cell Info Lite".

In my house, I got this measures:

RSSI: -51

RXLEV: 60

I know this measurements represents the received signal. I mean... the greater the value, the higher is the power received by the phone.

I would like to understand which are the differences between  two measurements and why they have so different values?

Comment: Don't know enough to provide a real answer, but a quick search informed me that RSSI is a power level, measured in dBm, but RXLEV is just an index that corresponds to different ranges of power. -51 dBm happens to fall into the range indexed by an RXLEV of 60.

Comment: Didn't know about that. I looked for RXLEV on Google and found the same information.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse square law attenuation of path loss or Friss Loss is the main factor followed by blocking effects of trees, or metal mesh or patio and then inverse phase reflection cancellation ( Ricean losses).  If 1W is +30dBm then it quickly drops in level to some distance ? 500m ? to -80dBm to noise threshold -90~-100dBm.   Depending on the RF band where speed and signal strength can affect performance tradeoffs, the % signal may be from 0 to 30% and excess signal strength from 30 to 100% , but this is just an estimate on my part.

Basically RSSi voltage is converted using log Amps with calibrated dBm and signal level in 0-100% is a linear conversion spanning more than 5 decades. (est.)

Comment: Hello Tony. Thank you for clarifying about RSSI measurement. I think combing your answer with Shamtam I perfectly understood the concepts. Have a nice day!